# how to use my table-valued function in view?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table-valued function to split a string to 3 part of it and I use it in my View.

when I use one of this part its work currectly:

```
SELECT  dbo.Health_Komak2.CDate AS HK2CreatedDateMiladi,----> (select yyyy from dbo.[DateToShamsiSepratePart](dbo.Health_Komak2.CDate)) as xxxxx, Ain74ID, 
     dbo.Health_Komak2_Paymnets.Price AS HK2Pprice from .......
```

but when I use 3 part to show in view like below :

```
    SELECT  dbo.Health_Komak2.CDate AS HK2CreatedDateMiladi,----> (select yyyy,mm,dd from dbo.[DateToShamsiSepratePart](dbo.Health_Komak2.CDate)) as xxxxx, Ain74ID, 
     dbo.Health_Komak2_Paymnets.Price AS HK2Pprice from .......
```

I get this error in SQL server  :

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

how can i show **yyyy** and **mm** and **dd** in my main view ?

Comment: If I'm following you right, why can't you just duplicate the first subquery 2 more times and select `mm` and `dd` in the other 2 respectively as separate columns?

Comment: You can use your table-valued function in a CROSS APPLY

Comment: you say why did I use 3 times from query to get yyyy and mm and dd ? because of redundancy and performance .

Answer (score 0):

after my research as John Cappelletti said, I can use Cross apply in my query. with cross apply we can return more than one column.

```
SELECT ---> c.yyyy,c.mm,c.dd, dbo.tbs_InsuranceCompany.Title AS InsuranceName, dbo.Health_Coverages.Coverages AS HCoveragesName, dbo.Health_Komak2.CDate AS HK2CreatedDateMiladi,  dbo.AinName74.Descr AS AinName74Name, dbo.Health_Coverages.Ainame_74_ID AS AinName74ID, 
     dbo.Health_Komak2_Paymnets.Price AS HK2Pprice FROM  dbo.Health_Komak2 INNER JOIN      ........>  cross apply  dbo.[DateToShamsiSepratePart](dbo.Health_Komak2.CDate) c
```